# Regex for Two Empty Spaces at End of Sentence Containing Specified Word

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

Is there anyway to use regex to find consecutive whitespace characters at the end of a sentence containing a specified word? In the example below, I would want to capture just the two white spaces following the last "WORD" in which the sentence starts with "TOTAL." The number of words following the "TOTAL" would vary, but there wouldn't be an additional whitespaces between the words, just at the end.

```py
TOTAL WORD WORD WORD WORD
```

I tried to use the following pattern (python flavor) in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9EPD5U/1):

```
(?:(?:TOTAL)(?:.+?(?=\s{2})))\s{2}
```

but couldn't find a way to exclude capturing the words prior to the whitespace.

Comment: There can be two (or more) whitespaces following the last "WORD" in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
import re

string = 'TOTAL WORD WORD WORD WORD  '

match = re.findall('^TOTAL.*\w(  +)$', string)
print(match)
```

Output:

```
['  ']
```

Explanation:

- `^TOTAL` start at the beginning of the sentence with "TOTAL"
- `.*\w` match anything up to the last letter in the sentence
- `(  +)$` capture any number of spaces greater than 2 at the end of the sentence

Comment: This is close to what I need, but, to clarify, the I wouldn't be able to specify the last "WORD" and the sentence wouldn't necessarily end with just two white spaces.

Comment: I see, I have edited the answer. Now that should capture any number of consecutive white spaces (at least 2) at the end of a sentence starting with "TOTAL".

Comment: This looks to be working. Is there any reason why the python re.findall function only returns the blank spaces, while, when putting the same pattern into regex101, it looks to be grabbing the whole sentence?

Comment: Just use `^TOTAL.*\w {2,}$`

Comment: I only want to capture two white spaces, not the words before it

Comment: regex101 seems to only grab the spaces at the end when I try it, not the whole sentence.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but when I paste your code above into regex101 python flavor match function, I'm seeing everything highlighted into two separate groups

Comment: That's normal, but only the 2nd group (green) is a capture group - if you look at the top middle of the regex101 screen there should be a green message saying "1 match".

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, make sure you mark it as the accepted answer, as per Stack Overflow rules :)